# custom action plugin with ConfigurationForm

Tags: 8, plugins, actions

I am trying to create a custom action with Configuration Form Field . I am able to create Action and it is being displayed on content page ( `/admin/content` ) , but I am not able to find the path to configure the fields in the Action Plugin.Can anyone please let me know the path to configure the Action Plugin ?

My Code as follows :

**UpdateNodeTitle.php**

```
namespace Drupal\action_plugin_examples\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\Core\Action\ConfigurableActionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Provides a an Update node title action.
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "action_plugin_examples_update_node_title",
 *   label = @Translation("Update node title"),
 *   type = "node",
 *   category = @Translation("Custom")
 * )
 *
 */
class UpdateNodeTitle extends ConfigurableActionBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return ['title' => ''];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['title'] = [
      '#title' => $this->t('New title'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['title'],
    ];
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->configuration['title'] = $form_state->getValue('title');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access($node, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {
    /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
    $access = $node->access('update', $account, TRUE)
      ->andIf($node->title->access('edit', $account, TRUE));
    return $return_as_object ? $access : $access->isAllowed();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function execute($node = NULL) {
    /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
    $node->setTitle($this->configuration['title'])->save();
  }

}
```

**action_plugin_examples.schema.yml**

```
action_plugin_examples.configuration.action_plugin_examples_update_node_title:
  type: mapping
  label: 'Configuration for "Update node title" action'
  mapping:
    title:
      type: string
      label: Title
```

**system.action.action_plugin_examples_update_node_title.yml**

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - action_plugin_examples
  module:
    - node
    - pathauto
id: action_plugin_examples_update_node_title
label: 'Update Node Title'
type: node
plugin: action_plugin_examples_update_node_title
configuration: {  }
```

I have seen a similar Action Plugin in core as well but can not find the path to configure the Plugin. [AssignOwnerNode](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21src%21Plugin%21Action%21AssignOwnerNode.php/class/AssignOwnerNode/8.9.x) 
Another Contributed module with similar functionality [custom pub](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/custom_pub/-/blob/8.x-1.x/src/Plugin/Action/SetCustomPublishOptionValue.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the core module **Actions** first to be able to configure action plugins in UI.

Then you can access the actions overview page:

**/admin/config/system/actions**

On the top of the page your new plugin should be present in the select list for creating advanced actions. When you select the plugin you should see the configuration form of your plugin:

**/admin/config/system/actions/add/action_plugin_examples_update_node_title**

Since you have already provided an action configuration in a YAML file you should also see a configured instance of your plugin in the available actions list.

Comment: thank you for the answer.