# Add a custom action on admin content page

Tags: entities, actions

I want to add a custom action to the dropdown on the admin content page (/admin/content) as shown in the screenshot below using Drupal 9. The views module is enabled so that form is part of the view.

[image]

I have found that [actions are now plugins](https://www.drupal.org/node/2020549) so I should just need to create a new plugin for my custom action.

I've used the actions found in `/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Action/Plugin/Action/` as an example for my new action so just created a new plugin that extends `EntityActionBase` add added the relevant methods.

I have a custom module called `shop_scrape`.
I created the file `shop_scrape/src/Plugin/Action/ScrapeAction.php`

That file contains:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\shop_scrape\Plugin\Action\ScrapeAction.
 */

namespace Drupal\shop_scrape\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Action\Plugin\Action\EntityActionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Action;
use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Scrape a page.
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "entity:scrape_action",
 *   label = @Translation("Scrape a page"),
 *   deriver = "Drupal\shop_scrape\Plugin\Action\EntityScrapeActionDeriver",
 * )
 */
class ScrapeAction extends EntityActionBase
{

  /**'
   * ScrapeAction constructor.
   * @param array $configuration
   * @param $plugin_id
   * @param $plugin_definition
   * @param EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   */
  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager)
  {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $entity_type_manager);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition)
  {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('entity_type.manager')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function executeMultiple(array $entities)
  {
    foreach ($entities as $entity) {
      \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage('Scrape ' . $entity->id());
    }
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function execute($object = NULL)
  {
    $this->executeMultiple([$object]);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access($object, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE)
  {
    $access = AccessResult::allowed();
    return $return_as_object ? $access : $access->isAllowed();
  }

}
```

Then I also created a `EntityScrapeActionDeriver` that for now just returns true:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\shop_scrape\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;

/**
 * Provides an action deriver that finds scrapable entity types.
 *
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Action\Plugin\Action\PublishAction
 * @see \Drupal\Core\Action\Plugin\Action\UnpublishAction
 */
class EntityScrapeActionDeriver extends EntityActionDeriverBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function isApplicable(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    return true;
    //return $entity_type->getLabel() == 'page';
  }

}
```

But my custom action is not appearing. Are there other steps I need to take or have I done something wrong?

Comment: does this help https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295329/custom-action-plugin-with-configurationform

Comment: You need to add type key as well in annotation

Comment: I wasn't sure about the type key, the core Email action has one, but Delete and Publish don't. I just tried adding a type but didn't change anything. And yes, that question looks like it will help lots!

Comment: After adding type key did you clear cache or check by uninstalling and reinstalling the module?

Comment: @FelixEve, are you trying to add the action only for nodes or for all entity types?

Comment: @4k4 Just nodes of a particular bundle. But if it just applies to all nodes that is also fine, I can filter at the execute step.

Comment: OK, then you don't need a deriver for entity types and you can add the type directly in annotations as @miststudent2011 commented.

Comment: Ok, that is good to know. The code in the linked question has made things much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code which creates a custom action plugin which modifies node title.

**action_plugin_examples/src/Plugin/Action/ArchiveNode.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\action_plugin_examples\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\Core\Action\ActionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\ContainerFactoryPluginInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Drupal\pathauto\PathautoState;

/**
 * Provides an Archive Node Action.
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "action_plugin_examples_archive_node",
 *   label = @Translation("Archive Node"),
 *   type = "node",
 *   category = @Translation("Custom")
 * )
 */
class ArchiveNode extends ActionBase implements ContainerFactoryPluginInterface {


  /**
   * The Messenger service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Messenger\MessengerInterface
   */
  protected $messenger;

  /**
   * Logger service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $logger;

  /**
   * The path alias manager.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\path_alias\AliasManagerInterface
   */
  protected $aliasManager;

  /**
   * Language manager for retrieving the default Langcode.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface
   */
  protected $languageManager;

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    $instance = new static($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition);
    $instance->logger = $container->get('logger.factory')->get('action_plugin_examples');
    $instance->messenger = $container->get('messenger');
    $instance->aliasManager = $container->get('path_alias.manager');
    $instance->languageManager = $container->get('language_manager');
    return $instance;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function access($node, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {
    /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */
    $access = $node->access('update', $account, TRUE)
      ->andIf($node->title->access('edit', $account, TRUE));
    return $return_as_object ? $access : $access->isAllowed();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function execute($node = NULL) {

    /** @var \Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node */

    $language = $this->languageManager->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();

    $old_alias = $this->aliasManager->getAliasByPath('/node/' . $node->id(), $language);

    $title = $node->getTitle();
    $date = $node->created->value;
    $year = date('Y', $date);
    // $old_alias = $node->path->alias;
    $new_title = $this->t('[Archive] | @title', ['@title' => $title]);
    $node->setTitle($new_title);
    $node->setSticky(FALSE);
    $node->setPromoted(FALSE);

    $new_alias = '/archive/' . $year . $old_alias;
    $node->set("path", [
      'alias' => $new_alias,
      'langcode' => $language,
      'pathauto' => PathautoState::SKIP,
    ]);

    $node->save();

    $message = $this->t('Node with NID : @id Archived.', ['@id' => $node->id()]);

    $this->logger->notice($message);
    $this->messenger->addMessage($message);

  }

}
```

**action_plugin_examples/config/optional/system.action.action_plugin_examples_archive_node.yml**

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - action_plugin_examples
  module:
    - node
    - pathauto
id: action_plugin_examples_archive_node
label: 'Archive Node'
type: node
plugin: action_plugin_examples_archive_node
configuration: {  }
```

**Note** : plugin **yml** file needs to be in the below format.

> system.action.<plugin_id>.yml

Comment: I placed this code in a plugin but it didn't create an action, however the code from the question you linked to has created an action so I'm now on the right path. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you need to create action_plugin_examples/config/optional/system.action.action_plugin_examples_archive_node.yml file as well to get it detected.

Added to answer.