# How to invoke a custom operation in Views

Tags: views, 9

I have a View that lists some nodes. Each node instance has a boolean - "Spam" - that defaults to FALSE.

In the view there is an "Operations" column where there shall be a link with the anchor text "Flag as spam".  When the user clicks on that link, the value of the boolean Spam field for that node becomes "TRUE".

I found this tutorial: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/howtos/how-to-add-a-column-with-dynamically-generated-action-buttons - but it is for Drupal 7.

However, what do I need to do to list a custom operation (with clickable link or button) in an "Operations" column produced by Views?

Comment: Maybe you can try like this https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295329/custom-action-plugin-with-configurationform

Comment: Those are not "actions" they are "operations". Actions would be used for Views Bulk Operations.

Comment: @sonfd Thanks a lot for your correction. I've edited the question to use the correct terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are "operations". That view field is controlled by the [EntityOperations](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.3.x/core/modules/views/src/Plugin/views/field/EntityOperations.php) field.

It's pretty easy to add a new operation for an entity by implementing [hook_entity_operation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_operation/9.3.x).

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Implements hook_entity_operation().
 */
function mymodule_entity_operation(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $operations = [];
  if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node' && someOtherCondition($entity)) {
    $operations['flag_as_spam'] = [
      'title' => t('Flag as Spam'),
      // Replace with the route you've created to set the node value.
      'url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.node.canonical', ['node' => $entity->id()]),
      'weight' => 50,
    ];
  }
  return $operations;
}
```