# Make a custom action with form

Tags: forms, 10, actions

I am trying to make a custom user action where the selected users will have a node created manually, however I need to create a form to save the data that this node will have, such as: title, start date, end date.
I have this code in my `my_module/Plugin/Action/ActionTest.php`

```
    <?php

namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\Core\Action\ActionBase;
use Drupal\views_bulk_operations\Action\ViewsBulkOperationsActionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Drupal\Core\Action\ConfigurableActionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Plugin\PluginFormInterface;
/**
 * Create custom action
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "test_action",
 *   label = @Translation("Test action"),
 *   type = "user",
 * )
 */
class ActionTest extends ViewsBulkOperationsActionBase implements PluginFormInterface {

    use StringTranslationTrait;
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function execute($entity = NULL) {

        $nid = $entity->id();
        $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

        $payment = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->create([
          'type' => 'payments',
          'title' => "Payment ${nid}",
          'langcode' => 'es',
          'field_payment_state' => 1,
          'field_user' => $nid,
          'field_last_plan_purchased' => 2156
        ]);
        $payment->save();
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);
    $form['title'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Title'),
      '#required' => TRUE,
    );

    return $form;
  }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function access($object, AccountInterface $account = NULL, $return_as_object = FALSE) {


    return true;
  }

}
```

But I can't get the selected action to go to the form, any idea on how I can achieve this?

I have the .schema.yml file like this

```
action.configuration.my_module:
 type: test_action
 label: 'Action custom'
```

and the configuration .yml file

```
langcode: es
status: true
dependencies:
 module:
   - user
id: test_action
label: 'Action custom'
type: user
plugin: test_action
configuration: {  }
```

I'm using drupal 10.1.4 and php 8.1
I appreciate any answer you can give me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [custom action plugin with ConfigurationForm](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/295329/custom-action-plugin-with-configurationform)

Comment: In this case, the form would not be the form to configure the action, but the node create form, which would be the output of the action.

Comment: All the classes implemented by a module are in a *src* directory. Some classes are required to be placed in a specific sub-directory of the *src* directory.

Answer (score 1):

In above code this **"system.action.test_action.yml" file missing** : **add** this **file** inside this folder: **module/config/optional**, **only then custom action 'll start appear under action select list**

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
 module:
   - user
id: test_action
label: 'Test action'
type: user
plugin: test_action
configuration: {  }
```

After this newly added "Test action" start appear in select list of Action field on people listing page(/admin/people)

**Note:** Make sure uninstall then install module so that "system.action.test_action.yml" config installed

After **adding** this file "**system.action.test_action.yml**" at proper folder structure, only then **action** 'll start **appear**.

**ActionTest.php need to place here**: my_module/**src**/Plugin/Action/ActionTest.php
instead of here my_module/Plugin/Action/ActionTest.php

Here in this file name convention : system.action.test_action.yml , test_action denotes machine name of custom action plugin

**If you want to configure action from UI along with custom action with the ConfigurationForm**

1. install "Actions" module in the core
2. Then visit to the actions overview page: /admin/config/system/actions
3. Here you 'll see "Create an advanced action" field, select the "Test action"(newly added custom action) from drop down & then click on create button
4. Then form 'll appear , fill the value in the field & click on save
5. Now the "Newly added custom action" 'll appear in available action list

Note : In this approach you don't need to create "system.action.test_action.yml" file

I have noticed this buildConfigurationForm() not defined, so need to remove this line:
$form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. But I did the same as you said, I deleted the code, I also added the folders to the src, I added the file to the module/config/optional folder but when I click on it, my custom form does not appear.

Comment: I suggested two approaches but if you want to see your custom form then you need to follow steps mentioned above in points form  (1-5) points, you can revert the changes that you done as it is part of  another approach